# Make all elements in pause cleared (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, pause

I have more than two elements in one frame that I would like to have in `\pause`.
But the `\pause` make me appear only the next element cleared.

I want that all elements in the same frame in pause appear cleared and then go colored one by one. How can I do?

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
 \begin{block}{}

 \end{block}
  \pause
 \begin{block}{}

 \end{block}
  \pause
 \begin{block}{}

 \end{block}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `\onslide` and `\alert` commands of the OVERLAY section of the Beamer's manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[<+-|alert@+>]\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A small explanation:

`[<+->]` tells Beamer that the default overlay will be to show each item one by one.

`alert@+` tells Beamer to color differently the current item.

And `[<+-|alert@+>]` make the both.

Result:

[image]

**Edit**

Like that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
\begin{block}<1-4>{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1,2-4> A
\item<1,3-4> B
\item<1,4> C
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: mmm, it doesn't solve the problem. I want that when I change the frame, all elements in pause result cleared end then get colored one by one.

Comment: I have updated my answser